# How do I read the first line of a string?

Tags: python, string

```
my_string = """This is my first line,
this is my second line, and...

...this is my fourth line!"""
```

How can I store the first line of that (`This is my first line,`) into a separate string? I attempted to use `.readline()` from another similar question, however I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'`

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Use [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to split the string on a newline, and grab the first item from the result:

```
my_string.partition('\n')[0]
```

This is the most efficient method if you only need to split a string in a single location. You could use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) too:

```
my_string.split('\n', 1)[0]
```

You do then need to tell the method to only split once, on the first newline, as we discard the rest.

Or you could use the [`.splitlines()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
my_string.splitlines()[0]
```

but this has to create separate strings for every newline in the input string so is not nearly as efficient.

Comment: i don't quite understand this sentence, could you explain a little? `I instructed ... rest`

Comment: @Lei paraphrasing: Because we only are interested in the first element and throw away the remainder, I used two arguments so Python splits the string into two parts. There is no point in splitting more than once.

Comment: Does `split('\n',1)` method use less ram in that case?

Comment: @Phineas `str.split()` creates new string objects (and a list object to hold them), and `.split("\n", 1)` creates just two new string objects. However, those two objects duplicate the string content of the first object, plus a per-object overhead (reference counts, length, other bookkeeping data) that's rather minimal in size, so it won't make *much* difference. If the input string is 1000 characters long, and you split on newlines, the new additional string objects will have nearly 1000 characters between them (minus the newline characters, but plus the overhead per object).

Comment: @Phineas: if you have memory issues working with a *lot* of string data, perhaps you need to consider not loading as much text into your code at the same time, rather than worry about how much ram `str.splitlines()` versus `str.split("\n", 1)` is going to use.

Comment: @Phineas: note that creating new objects has a cost per object, time spent allocating some memory somewhere, constructing the bookkeeping information, etc. That's where `.split("\n", 1)[0]` wins over `.splitlines()[0]`. Memory footprint doesn't really matter here.

Answer (score 6):

readline is used i conjuction with a stream. you could use StringIO if you insist on using readline:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

sio = StringIO(my_string)
for sline in sio.readlines():
    print sline
```

I would do

```
 for line in my_string.split('\n'):
        print line
```

or do

```
import re
for line in re.split('\n', my_string):
    print line
```

Comment: @e-info128 macOS hasn't been using '\r' since 2001, it uses '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()`:

```
my_string = """This is my first line,
this is my second line, and...

...this is my fourth line!"""

lines = my_string.split('\n')
```