# Python: find string in line file, empty output

Tags: python, line

I searched SO to find the line # of input txt file with a specific string. [How do I read the first line of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833266/how-do-i-read-the-first-line-of-a-string) Yet I do not get any output, it is empty. I use the following python code:

```
with open(input_f) as input_data:
    print input_f  # test if reading correct file: yes
    for line in input_f:  # originally  'in input_data': no output
        if line.split('\t', 1)[0] == 'ABC':  # string before tab
        #if line.startswith('ABC'):  ... also empty output
            print line  # nothing is printed
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to loop over input_data, not input_f.

Comment: Show us the input file.

Comment: you are iterating over input_f, which is the path to the file, and not input_data, which is the file object

Comment: You should elaborate more, it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over `input_f` instead of `input_data` in your for-loop :)

Answer (score 1):

`input_f` is the path to the file; `input_data` is the associated file object, which is what the `for` loop should be using.

Maybe it didn't work when you used `input_data` because you didn't have tabs in your lines, or any lines that began with `ABC`; not being able to see the input, it is impossible to say.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to get the first line in your file that starts by 'ABC\t', then, the easier, more efficient and more Pythonic way to do so is:

```
with open(input_f) as input_data:
    your_value = next(line for line in input_data if line.startswith('ABC\t'))
```

See as others say, that you need to iter over input_data (the file descriptor), and not input_f (the string with the file path).