# Printing a single line in a multi-line string

Tags: python, automation

I manage to use pytesseract to convert an invoice image into text.

The multi-line string looks like this:

```
Receipt No: 20191220.001
Date: 20 December 2019
Invoice amount: $400.00
```

I would like to extract invoice number, just the number (i.e.: 20191220.001) using substring. I manage to get the start index through `index = string.find('Receipt No: ')` but when I use the substring function to extract the number `print(string[index:])` I got the following result:

```
20191220.001
Date: 20 December 2019
Invoice amount: $400.00
```

But I only wanted to extract the first line. The invoice numbers are not defined at only 12 characters, there might be more or less depending on the vendor. How do I only extract the invoice number? I'm doing this to automate an accounting process.

Comment: if you know its the first line always then just read first line and then do string.find() on that line.

Comment: This is how you found the start index, I guess what you need is the end index. Then you can slice by `string[index1:index2]`. Think a little bit more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read the first line of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833266/how-do-i-read-the-first-line-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split`:

```
s = '''Receipt No: 20191220.001
Date: 20 December 2019
Invoice amount: $400.00'''

number = s.split('Receipt No: ')[1].split('\n')[0]
print(number)
```

Output:

```
20191220.001
```

Or if you want to use `find`, you can do in this way:

```
index1 = s.find(':')
index2 = s.find('\n')
print(s[index1+1:index2].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re
s = """
Receipt No: 20191220.001
Date: 20 December 2019
Invoice amount: $400.00"""
p = re.compile("Receipt No\: (\d+.\d+)")
result = p.search(s)
index = result.group(1) #'20191220.001'
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate your string in a list with split by "\n"
You will get each part of a string separated by newline as a list element. You can then take the part you want

```
string = """Receipt No: 20191220.001
Date: 20 December 2019
Invoice amount: $400.00"""

your_list = string.split("\n")
data = your_list[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with split function.

with open("filename",'r') as dataload:

```
for i in dataload.readlines():

    if "Receipt No:" in i:

        print(i.split(":")[1].strip())
```

output-

20191220.001

if "Receipt No:" in i: ---> you can change if "**" parameter as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the first line, you can find the first occurence of line ending character as the end of your number. Notice that the start of your number is the end of the substring ("Receipt No: ") while find function return the start of the substring.

```py
string = '''Receipt No: 20191220.001
Date: 20 December 2019
Invoice amount: $400.00'''
sub = 'Receipt No: '
start = string.find(sub) + len(sub)
end = string.find('\n')
print(string[start:end])
```

If you also care about other lines. You can use split and process each line separately.

```py
lines = string.split('\n')
sub = 'Receipt No: '
index = lines[0].find(sub) + len(sub)
print(lines[0][index:])
# Process line 1
# Process line 2
```